# Debian OS kernel versions difference: 3.16.51-3 vs 3.16.51-3+deb8u1

Tags: linux, operating-system, debian, kernel, version

My OS is the following:
$ uname -v

## 1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-3 (2017-12-13)

Question: Are 3.16.51-3 and 3.16.51-3+deb8u1 considered the same? Or are they different?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are different.

the 3.16.51-3+deb8u1 is an newer/updated one. The version number in front of the "+" is the upstream-version and "+deb..." is the debian version like it's specified in

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/

No debian version means it's the initial debian version.